# how to get the right class name innerHTML content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="Name">
    <div class="Image"></div>

    <ul>
                <li><h5><span class"myName">I want this text</span></h5></li>
                  <li class="description">The description</li>
        </ul>
        <button class="myButton">My Button</button
</div>
```

(multiple items with the same structure)

if my structure is constructed this way,
how can I get the class myName to have its content as a variable?

```
$(".myButton").click(function () {
    var itemName =    $(this).siblings(".myName").innerHTML   ??
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to get it:

```
$(".myButton").click(function () {
  var itemName = $(this).parent().find(".myName").html();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem is that you have an error in you HTML. You have

```
<span class"myName">
```

instead of

```
<span class="myName">
```

and this makes all difference, because your class selector will not work property. Oh, you're also missing the ">" in the closing of button tag.

Here's the fixed HTML:

```
<div class="Name">
    <div class="Image"></div>
    <ul>
        <li><h5><span class="myName">I want this text</span></h5></li>
        <li class="description">The description</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="myButton">My Button</button>
</div>
```

And here's the jQuery that works with it:

```
$(".myButton").click(function() {
    var itemName = $(this).parent().find('.myName').html();
    alert(itemName);
});
```

You had missed the closing parenthesis as well...

I created a fiddler so you can test it: http://jsfiddle.net/juj3W/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(".myButton").click(function () {
    var itemName = $(".myName", $(this).parent()).text();
                   //find class in parent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemName = $(this).prev('ul').find('.myName').html();
```